# Getting error when trying to use OPENQUERY Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

When I run this query:

```
SELECT *   
FROM OPENQUERY([XXX], 'SELECT * 
                       FROM Database.Table 
                       WHERE (MBCONO=650) AND MBCUNO LIKE a%' )
```

I get the error:

> OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "XXX" returned message
>   "Token %ÂŸFOR SKIP WITH FETCH ORDER UNION EXCEPT OPTIMIZE SQLSTATE:
>   42601, SQLCODE: -104".
>
> Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 An error
>   occurred while preparing the query "SELECT * FROM Database.Table WHERE
>   (MBCONO=650) AND MBCUNO LIKE a%'" for execution against OLE DB
>   provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "LAWSON".

I can run the same query without `AND MBCUNO LIKE a%` successfully.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8277/discussion-between-roka-and-a-elm5zngy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you change your original SQL Statement as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY([XXX], 'SELECT * FROM database.table where left(MBCUNO, 1) = ''a'' and (MBCONO=650) ' )
```

This has the two variable swopped around, and the `like %` exchanged for a `left(mbcuno,1)`.

Ensure that all your table & column references are correct